# Is there any indicator for squad health on the main HUD?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Looking at the main HUD of the game, there seems to be no indicator of squad health, only their picture (which doesn't seem to indicate anything other than *dead*) and Shepard's health/shields (for obvious reasons).  Pausing the game does not seem to bring up any indicator either.

The only thing I could find was the actual health levels in the Squad menu, but this is nonideal in the heat of combat in order to glance at who is about to die.  Any idea if there is a way to display them without a mod, or is it something planned in a future patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easily-accessible indicator of squad health. I sent my squad mates head first into a suicidal combat and watched them take damage, but it was not reflected in their tiny HUD pictures.

I have seen the portraits flash briefly, but I don't know what caused that to happen.

There's likely no way of showing this information on console versions of ME3, but it's probable that someone will mod this feature into the PC version.

Comment: Just as I feared.  I understand minimalistic and clean, but that's relatively important data to know in combat.